# How to keep a Service alive?

Tags: android, service, whatsapp, huawei-mobile-services

How Whatsapp service keep working in background in huawei phones ?

I removed whatsapp of protected apps but Whatsapp service not closed in screen 
off time.

I'm writing critical app that need to run every time but my service killed in screen off.

I want to write service like Whatsapp or AirDroid service
anyone can explain about that ?

I mean how to write service that specially not close by screen off in HUAWEI phones

This is my service code

> AppLifeService

```
public class AppLifeService extends Service {
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

    return null;
}



@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);


    startForeground(5, AppLifeReciever.createNotification(this));


    return  START_STICKY;
}


@Override
public void onDestroy() {


    //startService(new Intent(this, AppLifeService.class)); Updated : not need


    super.onDestroy();

}
}
```

Comment: did you check on different versions of android os? In which os version service is stopping?

Comment: if your service is indeed foreground (as you're calling startForeground) , then it cannot be killed and the non-dismissable notification is a testament to that. when do you call stopForeground?

Answer (score 5):

You need to create a `Service` to "reopen" `BroadcastService` automatically when it's closed.

**For example:**

**BroadcastService**

```
public class MyBroadcastService extends BroadcastReceiver
{

 @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent)
    {
     //do something
    }
}
```

**Service to "reopen" automatically**

```
public class MyService extends Service
{

@Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        // Handler will get associated with the current thread,
        // which is the main thread.
        super.onCreate();
        ctx = this;

    }

 @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        return null;
    }

@Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        //Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return START_STICKY;
    }

//launch when its closed
@Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();
        sendBroadcast(new Intent("YouWillNeverKillMe"));
        Toast.makeText(this, "YouWillNeverKillMe TOAST!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

**Declare on your `AndroidManifest.XML`**

```
<receiver android:name=".BroadcastServicesBackground.MyBroadcastService">
            <intent-filter>
                <!--That name (YouWillNeverKillMe) you wrote on Myservice-->
                <action android:name="YouWillNeverKillMe"/>

                <data android:scheme="package"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                 <!--To launch on device boot-->
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".Services.MyService"/>
```

Comment: i tested in huawei phones and service close without calling onDestroy

Answer (score 5):

> **@Sohail Zahid** Answer tells you a way to `repeatedly` start a service ***again and again*** when stopped. But in order to keep a service alive like playing a song in a background.

The best Approach I found is

```
startForeground(int, Notification)
```

where int value must be unique for every notification

You'll need to supply a `Notification` to the method which is displayed in the Notifications Bar in the Ongoing section. **In this way the app will keep alive in background without any interuption.**

Answer (score 4):

Service with `START_STICKY` in retrun `onStartCommand()` will start again automatically you dont need to start it again in `onDestroy()`

```
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {

      //  startService(new Intent(this, AppLifeService.class));
        super.onDestroy();

    }
```

Comment: Thanks ,Post Updated . but i specialy talk about Huawei phones
in time that app not added to "Protected Apps" list

Comment: @hamidjahandideh sory i have no idea specifically about Huawei phones.

Comment: Information for new users coming to this thread, It is not guaranteed that onDestroy will be called in every case.