# Restart service as the app gets killed everytime

Tags: android, service, background, chat

I have a Chat application which runs in background also, so when I kill my application in any way be it swiping out of the recent app or killing the app inside setting, I want my Service to restart everytime and it should be awake all time untill the application is running. I have tried Broadcast Receiver to restart my service.

```
 @Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.d("MyService", "onDestroy");

        sendBroadcast(new Intent("RestartService"));
}
```

And I have also tried onTaskRemoved

```
@Override
public void onTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onTaskRemoved:");

    Intent restartServiceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), this.getClass());
    restartServiceIntent.setPackage(getPackageName());

    PendingIntent restartServicePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, restartServiceIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
    AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmService.set(
            AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,
            SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000,
            restartServicePendingIntent);

    super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
}
```

and also in startCommand I have user START_STICKY, but nothing seems to work.
Any help on this would be appreciated..

Comment: Did you try startForeground. I believe that keeps your service running. You do have to supply a notification though

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474290/how-keep-alive-service-android/38474416#38474416

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE can you please provide any link or code about how to do it.?

Comment: @TanveerBulsari; https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html. There is a section about `startForeground` there