# How to make a service alive?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-service, android-alarms, android-jobscheduler

I want to make service running in an interval but service is being killed after some time when app is closed. **I know similar questions have been asked multiple times but none of them could answer for what I am looking for.**
I have tried following approaches

**Alarm Manager**

By setting the time interval for a pending intent to a broadcast receiver which further lead to run the service. *(It keep on working till app is running but it stopped when app is killed.)*

1. It keeps on working in Android 6.0 for long time interval till it is
   killed by App cleaner manually.
2. In android 8.0 + it is being killed
       as app is closed.

**JobSchedular**

I have also tried **JobSchedular** to run a **JobService** but it also killed as the app is closed in Android 8.0+. But it runs for a long time interval in android 6.0 till I run app cleaner and it is killed.

I admit that **it is not a good practice to keep service running** as it is the **loss of device resources**. But if someone wants to sync data after some time and generate notifications locally then What to do?

I have also tried cloud messages these are also not received when app is killed. [As mentioned here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive).
Various OS behaviors such as **Android O's background execution limits may interfere** with ability to complete work.

**On the other hand**

**Whats App** and **skype**  are generating notifications even if apps are closed and running app cleaner but it is not effecting **WhatsApp** notifications generator.

**What logical strategy these apps adopted that OS is not killing their processes?**

I have already tried   `android:stopWithTask="false"`   but it does not work. And I do not what to run the service in foreground as well. I have also [read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38474290/how-to-keep-a-service-alive). I have also tried to run service again by **timer when process is terminated**. (Not Worked)

Comment: You must rely in this case on Google cloud messaging.  As keeping a service alive by yourself is considered a waste of resources.

Comment: @AlanDeep!  Question is to handle that issue when app was killed and cloud messages could not received by FirebaseMessagingService.

Comment: check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30525784/android-keep-service-running-when-app-is-killed

Comment: @AlanDeep! I already asked in my question I do not want service as foreground since it will always have a notification.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/52258125/8615158

Comment: Moreover I have also tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/52708403/8615158 and it does not work for me.

Comment: I don't think you're getting me. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ is your bet here

Comment: I tried cloud messages but these are not generated when app is killed by OS. Point is what whatsapp doing to generate these notifications without being killed.